# Empty properties list on Neo4j browser 3.0.11

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

I tried to delete all content in my Neo4j 3.3 database through the Neo4j browser. I used:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

Unfortunately, the browser is keeping a list of old (obsolete) property keys, so that (after refilling the database) autocomplete still lists these property keys that are gone. Any way to get rid of them?

Comment: Do you still have any indexes or uniqueness constraints? If so, try dropping them.

Comment: Hi @JF Meier. Please, give me a feedback and let me know if the answer I provided helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/701), Neo4j Browser just display the data provided by Neo4j database through `CALL db.propertyKeys()`.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10941) in the Neo4j's Github repository about removing unused property keys from `db.propertyKeys()` results.

Since you are deleting all your nodes and relationships, you can alternatively delete all content of `<neo4j-home>/data/databases/graph.db/` folder and restart Neo4j service. But you will need to recreate all indexes and constraints.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on performing such deletions on AuraDB? It doesn't allow you to mess with `/graph.db`.